Console.WriteLine not applying overloaded ToString because of an implicit operator to double
Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:
// Implicit and explicit conversions are overloadable operators:

Note note = new Note (9);
Console.WriteLine(note);

Note n = (Note)554.37;
double x = n;
Console.WriteLine(n);
Console.WriteLine(x);

public struct Note
{
    int value;
    public int SemitonesFromA { get { return value; } }

    public Note (int semitonesFromA) { value = semitonesFromA; }

    // Convert to hertz
    public static implicit operator double (Note x) => 440 * Math.Pow (2, (double)x.value / 12);

    // Convert from hertz (accurate to the nearest semitone)
    public static explicit operator Note (double x) =>
        new Note ((int)(0.5 + 12 * (Math.Log (x / 440) / Math.Log (2)))); 
    
    public override string ToString() => $"{SemitonesFromA} semitones from A";
}

I would've expected
9 semitones from A
4 semitones from A
554.3652619537442

But I get
739.9888454232688
554.3652619537442
554.3652619537442

I think it's because in the "order of priorities" of Console.WriteLine, impliciting casting to double has more priority than calling .ToString() on the Object type. How does this work? How can I know by looking at the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0#overloads), which overloads is selected?

Should be : public override string ToString(int x) => $"x semitones from A";   The ToString() you are passing an int.

I think the term you are looking for is overload resolution

It can only pick double or object. Double is more specific than object. Basically, object will always be selected last. See also https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/#more-1806

It just picks "the closest" match.
Your expectation in for Console.Writeline to invoke ToString implicitly.
But it will not, if it has correct overload for the type. And Console.WriteLine infers correct overload, as Note is implicitly castable to double, which then matches the Console.WriteLine(double) overload exactly and does not proceed to call general overload with object? as type of parameter, which just invokes ToString method.
You can hover over your call to Console.WriteLine and see what overload will be used:

And if you change your implicit operator to explicit one, you would get what you expect:

